# Events for custom resources?

Tags: resources, sylius

I've created a new entity with [ResourcesBundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/index.html) but on the profiler I can't see the [Events](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/events.html).

Must I create manualy?

Creating an EventListener for `sylius.book.pre_create` doesn't do nothing.

### Adding Info

Hi anothertime lchrusciel.

This is my configuration for my resource:

```
dinamic_sylius_post:
    resource: |
        alias: dinamic.post
        path: blog/post
    type: sylius.resource

dinamic_sylius_admin_post:
    resource: |
        alias: dinamic.post
        section: admin
        templates: SyliusAdminBundle:Crud
        except: ['show', 'delete']
        redirect: index
        grid: dinamic_sylius_blog_post
    type: sylius.resource
    prefix: admin/
```

And on my bundle config I have this:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        dinamic.post:
            classes:
                model: Dinamic\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Entity\Post
                form:
                    default: Dinamic\Bundle\SyliusBlogBundle\Form\PostType
```

What I'm doing wrong then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is your custom resource you should look for `app.book.pre_create` event.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Controller/EventDispatcher.php#L45) event name depends on application name which is `sylius` for predefined Sylius resources, but if you defined your own, it usually `app`.

If you have followed Sylius docs about using ResourceBundle with your own resources you have found following config:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.book:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Book
```

So important part of this config is an alias of resource `app.book`. Dot split alias to application name(`app`) and resource name(`book`).

Same rules apply to crud generation config:

```
app_book:
resource: |
    alias: app.book
type: sylius.resource_api
```

Using `app` as a application name is Sylius recommendation, but you can arbitrary choose any other.

**Edit**

In your example this is an important part:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        dinamic.post:
            classes:
```

According to it, `dinamic` is an application name, and `post` is a resource name. So the following events should be triggered:

- dinamic.post.pre_create
- dinamic.post.post_create
- dinamic.post.pre_update
- dinamic.post.post_update
- dinamic.post.pre_delete
- dinamic.post.post_delete

Comment: Correct! But i can't find those events on Symfony2 debuger. `php app/console debug:event-dispatcher | grep dinamic` returns none :(

Comment: Sure, because according to this command definition it returns only `Registered Listeners Grouped by Event`. So if listener is not registered, event won't be listed.

Comment: I found the mistake, was mine, i declare my services but not under `services:` config. SORRY